# Trying to fit sentiment score in time series analysis in R

Tags: r, time-series, sentiment-analysis

I have extracted tweets from Twitter about Bitcoin. I have a total of 4383186 tweets extracted and after using sentiment analysis and taking the first difference(for stationarity purposes), I am left with a total of 2623105. So, when I am trying to run the following code:

```
First_diff$Sentiment_score
result:
[1]  -2   1  -1   2   0   0  -1   1   0  -1  -1  -5   5  -2   3   1  -6   5   0  -3   5  -2   0   0
  [25]  -4   1   2   1   3  -7   6  -3  -2  -1   2   2   1  -4   1  -2   3   1   0   3  -3  -1   3  -8
  [49]   6   0  -1  -2   7  -3   0  -2   2  -4   3  -1  -2   1   5  -7   3   1  -1   0   5  -5   1  -1
  [73]   0  -2   0  -1   4   1  -1  -1   3  -2  -6   6  -1   2   1  -8   1   2  -3   6   1   1   3  -7
  [97]   2   7 -10   5  -4  -1  -3  11  -6   0   8  -7   2  -2  -3   3   5   0  -5   5  -5   0  -2   1
 [121]   6  -6   4  -4   4  -6   4   1  -6   4  -3   2   3  -8   5   0   3   0  -6   3   2  -1   0   0
 [145]   3  -7   4  -3   3   0  -1  -4  10  -6   6  -5  -1   1   0  -1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0  -5
 [169]   4   1   2  -6   0   5  -3  -4   5   1   1  -2  -1   0  -2   2   6  -6   0   5  -3  -4   2  -2
 [193]  -3   5   0   0  -2   4   0  -2   0  -3   5  -6   4   8  -6  -1   0  -1  -5   4   1  -2   4  -1
 [217]   0   0   0  -1   1   7  -8  -4   4   3  -6   2  -4   5   2   0  -2   0   4  -3   1  -2   1  -1
 [241]  -2  -1   4   0  -1   1   1  -4   2  -3   7  -4  -2   3   5  -6   1   0   0  -1   0   0   0  -2
 [265]   3  -3   2  -2   2   4  -4   3  -3   1  -5   5   0   4  -3  -1  -3   5  -2   0   2  -7   2   2
 [289]  -2   7  -5  -3   4  -2   2  -1   4  -4   2  -2   4  -7   3   3  -2  -1   1  -6   4   1  -2  -1
 [313]   3  -3   4  -3   0  -3   4   1   3  -4   2  -1   2  -5   0   4  -4   0   2  -1  -1   4  -6   6
 [337]  -1   1  -1  -2   2  -2   2  -1  -2   2   1  -3   3  -3   3   1   0  -1   1   0  -1   3  -4   2
 [361]  -2   0  -4   3   4  -2   2  -4   2  -2   2   0   0   6  -5  -1  -5   6   0  -1  -1   2   1  -3
 [385]   1   2  -2   1   2  -2  -5   4   0  -2  -3   4  -1  -1   8 -10   3   0   2   1  -3   1  -1   3
 [409]  -5  -1   3   2   0   5  -5   1  -3  -3   0   5   2   0  -4   3   0  -6   3   6  -5  -2   2   4
 [433]  -3  -3  -1   1   4  -6   6   0   2  -2  -1  -3   5  -2  -2   3  -2  -1   1  -1  -2   4   5  -5
```

The above is just a small sample of the whole data

```
head(First_diff$Sentiment_score)
result:
[1] -2  1 -1  2  0  0
```

Which is weird? Since I have more than 2 million observations.
Nevertheless, I tried plotting the following in a timeseries graph with the following code, however this graph gives me back a graph with a black square all over the graph.

```
ts_tweet <- ts(First_diff$Sentiment_score, frequency = ..)
plot.ts(ts_tweet)
```

I used several different numbers in the frequency tab, but was not getting anything better. What am I doing wrong or am I forgetting to do? The data of the First_diff is a df with sentiment score column and date column. The date column goes from 2021-02-05 10:52:04 up to 2022-10-15 23:59:59.

Comment: What happens if you only attempt to plot the first 100 sentiment scores? I suspect attempting to pass it 2 million data points is causing some issues - the black square may be R's attempt to plot the rapidly oscillating sentiment score using lines and just ends up connecting the highest possible to the lowest possible in every spot

Comment: If I use only the first 100 observations from the sample, then the graph indeed looks much better. Is there no other way to use the whole sample? In the end, I am using the whole sample of the sentiment score to preict future values of bitcoin return using a garch model. I am doing this for my thesis, as I also need to show whether there is any trend/seasonality or any other pattern involved in the data. I was kind of expecting that the graph wouldn't hold up but gave it a go anyway.

Comment: I mean you don't need to plot the actual values for every point in order to analyze them, right? And almost certainly not as lines, points might work better if you're looking for a trend. It looks like the data is sound, it's just too much to plot in raw format. So either subsampling/aggregation/summarizing will show the actual answers you're interested in.

Comment: Ah great!@Dubukay maybe subsamples on exactly the same "ylim", should do the trick as the plots will be better in comparision. Any idea how muuch observation R can take in raw format?

Comment: @Dubukay, I was wondering if there is an easier way to let R plot different plots based on the rows. I have tried your solutions and for 100000 observations is seems like the graph looks much better. However, defining 2623105/100000=26 different different plots by hand in R seems a little bit too much. How can I define a for loop, such that R plots for example plot1 based on the rows 1:100000 and plot 2 based on rows 100001:200000? Even though defining a for loop and calling 26 diferent if/if else statements seems a bit too much work. Can I think of a better way to define my for loop?